# What creates a person's soul in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

I am curious about how a person's soul is created in the Harry Potter universe. Is it created by some sort of ancient magic that all humans have inside of them, or is there a certain place in the Harry Potter universe where souls are created and then souls from this place are magically sent to new born babies?

Is there anything written in Harry Potter canon that discusses this particular subject or has this subject ever been discussed by J. K. Rowling? I have been searching for an answer to this question on Google for the past couple of days but have not found one yet.

Comment: [Judging by Rowling's religious view, I would say God.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9133/57310)

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, the concept of a soul in Harry Potter is quite close to the common, religious concepts in Christianity. The specific part is only the idea to split it, by committing an evil deed, in order to create horcruxes and become immortal.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Harry Potter Wiki article on Souls](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Soul):

> The soul is the immaterial part of a being, which in many belief systems is held to live on after death. Wizards and witches, like Muggles, have sought to uncover the nature of the soul.

This suggests that the soul is a fundamental part of the human body, like the brain or the heart. The question is then like asking 'What creates a person's heart?' which doesn't really have a definitive answer.

Rowling has talked about [the effects of removing a person's soul](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/253831-you-can-exist-without-your-soul-you-know-as-long) but as far as I can tell she hasn't discussed exactly what a soul is or how they are created.

Comment: Note you need two new lines to from a paragraph break, I've edited so it now renders properly. You may also want to note that the Harry Potter wiki is a third party source and not always entirely reliable, it is best to try and find evidence from either what it cites or the primary source material (books/films) instead.

Comment: @ Bob_the_Jedi, the only problem with that is if the soul is part of the human body, then it should die when the body dies, but it doesn't die and instead lives on in the afterlife.

Comment: biologically speaking in the real world, I think we have a pretty good idea of what creates organs (if that is what you mean by 'a person's heart'). Ideally, unsourced wikis are not the best resources for an answer (as anyone can go edit and say whatever they want). The quote you have from Rowling is actually just an excerpt from book 3, so it would be better to include the actual text reference instead of making it appear as though she had some off-book comment about it. Welcome and keep answering!